# Audit Process in Informatica

Tags: statistics, informatica, audit-logging

I would need to capture the target table insert count and updated count once the session is completed successfully. I thought of using the session build-in variables to get these counts. Suggest me the best place to use these logic so that I can easily replicate this for all data loading mappings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have separate target transformations for inserts and updates (eg. MyTaregt_Insert & MyTarget_Update) you should be able to access those counts quite eaisly via variables: $PMMyTaregt_Insert@numAffectedRows and $PMMyTarget_Update@numAffectedRows. You can get more information here:

http://www.disoln.org/2012/09/An-ETL-Framework-for-Operational-Metadata-logging.html

Answer (score 0):

Best is to have reusable session at the end of each session to capture the information with post session variables. Else use the counter kind of framework as custom code in the mapping itself.